# Cumulative product for each element over x days in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to calculate for each element in a `Dataframe` `df1` the cumulative product over `x` days (for example 3). Is there an efficient way to do that? So far, I only know to generate a normal cumulative product over the rows, without fixing the lookback period to `x` days (=`df2`). For example:

- 2022-01-02 ID1: 1.0528 = (ignoring NaN) 0.94 * 1.12
- 2022-01-05 ID1: 1.2002 = 0.94 * 1.12 * 1.14
- 2022-01-09 ID1: 1.4045 = 1.12 * 1.14 * 1.10

Optimally, it would also ignore NaN values and calculate the cumulative return over the remaining numbers. So far I only know how to compute that by creating a copy and shifting it, but I would like to do calculate the cumulative product for many columns over 50 rows, which would not be efficient.

```
df1:
            ID1     ID2
Date        
2022-01-02  NaN     0.95
2022-01-05  0.94    0.98
2022-01-09  1.12    NaN
2022-01-10  1.14    1.02
2022-01-11  1.10    1.00
2022-01-12  0.92    0.82

df2:
            ID1     ID2
Date        
2022-01-02  1.0528  0.9309
2022-01-05  1.2002  0.9996
2022-01-09  1.4045  1.0200
2022-01-10  1.1537  0.8364
2022-01-11  1.0120  0.8200
2022-01-12  0.9200  0.8200
```

For reproducability:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2022-01-02', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12'],
    'ID1':[np.nan, 0.94, 1.12, 1.14, 1.1, 0.92], 
    'ID2':[0.95, 0.98, np.nan, 1.02, 1, 0.82]})
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
```

Thanks a lot for you suggestion!

Comment: So here with "three days" you actually mean three rows? Because the examples are using rows which are more than three days in total if you consider the date

Comment: I would approach this using a [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) then maybe a custom aggregation method to compute the product of the elements, maybe using [np.prod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1.fillna(1)[::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).agg(lambda x: x.prod())[::-1]
```

output:

```
                 ID1     ID2
Date                        
2022-01-02  1.052800  0.9310
2022-01-05  1.200192  0.9996
2022-01-09  1.404480  1.0200
2022-01-10  1.153680  0.8364
2022-01-11  1.012000  0.8200
2022-01-12  0.920000  0.8200
```

How does it work?

- rolling uses the previous rows (or is centered), here we reverse the array to compute an inverse rolling
- We fill the NaNs with 1 (we could also use np.nanprod)
- We use min_periods=1 to enable computation on less than 3 elements

Comment: @user2246849 I also like the custom indexer, too bad it is not included as parameter (like center)

Comment: Adding this to the accepted anwser : `df1[::-1].rolling(3, 1).apply(np.prod)[::-1]` gives the same result but may be less readable.

Comment: @SpaceBurger correct, actually `np.prod` ignores the NaNs if the input is a Series.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [custom rolling indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for forward-looking windows and [`np.nanprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanprod.html):

```
import numpy as np

# Window of index i includes rows [i:i+3).
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)

print(df.rolling(indexer, min_periods=1).apply(np.nanprod))
```

```
                 ID1     ID2
Date                        
2022-01-02  1.052800  0.9310
2022-01-05  1.200192  0.9996
2022-01-09  1.404480  1.0200
2022-01-10  1.153680  0.8364
2022-01-11  1.012000  0.8200
2022-01-12  0.920000  0.8200
```

Comment: A one-liner would be `df1[::-1].rolling(3, 1).apply(np.prod)[::-1]`

Comment: @SpaceBurger yes, but with `fillna(1)` (see mozway's answer)

Comment: @user2246849 no, fillna doesn't seem to be necessary, i get the same results and there is no need of using a lambda function with this ; but maybe i should add it to the new answer now that it has been accepted